# Trying to call getApplicationContext() on instance of Application class leads to null object reference error

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to do some networking in my Android app.

The sequence of events that leads up to my error are as follows:

In my fragment, I get a new instance of my VolleySingleton class if one does not already exist.

```
public static VolleySingleton getInstance() {
        if (vInstance == null) {
            vInstance = new VolleySingleton();
        }
        return vInstance;
    }
```

In creating an instance of VolleySingleton, I create a request queue and set it equal to Volley.newRequestQueue(myApplication.getContext());

```
    public class VolleySingleton {
    private static VolleySingleton sInstance = null;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    MyApplication myApplication = new MyApplication();

    private VolleySingleton() {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(myApplication.getAppContext());
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<>((int)(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1024/8));
            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public static VolleySingleton getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new VolleySingleton();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }
}
```

Now, myApplication is just an instance of the MyApplication class which extends Application, and getContext() simply calls getApplicationContext on an instance of MyApplication. Here is the code for the MyApplication class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication sInstance;
    public static final String API_KEY = "xxxxxxxx";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance=this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    public Context getAppContext() {
        return sInstance.getApplicationContext();
    }


}
```

The error seems to occur when I try to `return sInstance.getApplicationContext();`

I've managed to get identical code to work in a separate test project, so I'm at a loss here.

Here is my logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context com.xxxxxxxxx.chessgame.Models.MyApplication.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
            at com.xxxxxxxxx.chessgame.Models.MyApplication.getAppContext(MyApplication.java:28)
            at com.xxxxxxxxxx.chessgame.Networking.VolleySingleton.<init>(VolleySingleton.java:25)
            at com.xxxxxxxxx.chessgame.Networking.VolleySingleton.getInstance(VolleySingleton.java:42)
            at com.xxxxxxxx.chessgame.RecyclerViews.FragmentViewOne.onCreate(FragmentViewOne.java:95)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:913)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:842)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:859)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:152)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1071)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:851)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.Act
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? Post your logcat.

Comment: Where do you assign `myApplication` to an instance of `MyApplication`?

Comment: Outside of the constructor. I'll include the entire VolleySingleton class in my OP

Comment: And where in the Fragment to you call `getInstance()`?

Comment: In the onCreate: `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
        requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();


    }`

Comment: Have you declared your MyApplication class in manifest as name attribute in Application tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make sure you have declared your MyApplication class in manifest as **android:name="packagename.MyApplication"** in **application** tag

Comment: Thanks dude. U made my day/night :)

Answer (score 2):

> MyApplication myApplication = new MyApplication();

seems wrong.

You can change VolleySingleton's constructor and getInstance method to accept Context as argument.

The fact Application has onCreate method indicates, it's lifeclycle is managed by Android OS. You shouldn't directly call constructor just as you shouldn't do new Activity().
You can get instance of Application from e.g. [Activity#getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication())

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly well but the answer below addressed the real reason why MyApplication was causing problems.